# How to add space between in-line elements without using &nbsp

Tags: css, reactjs

I have to add space between two input fields without using `&nbsp`. I have tried to also add `{'  '}` but that made no difference

This is how they are rendered:

```
       return (
          <div className="side-by-side">
                <Input
                  style={{ marginRight: 100 }}
                  classname="flex w-49"
                  label="first name"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter first name..."
                  inputId="basicInput"
                  value={obj.firstName}                      
                ></Input>
                {'          '}
                <Input
                  classname="flex w-49"
                  label="last name"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter last name..."
                  inputId="basicInput"
                  value={obj.lastName}
                ></Input>
          </div>
```

And this is the css I'm using to get them in the same line

```
.side-by-side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 4px; //also tried to add a margin but that didn't work
}
```

Comment: you need to give margin to your input

Comment: Even if I add the margin, it doesn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are putting `margin-left` on the `side-by-side` container it will but margin on the whole container when you just want margin on the right input.

A simple solution which isn't fully supported in all browsers yet is putting `gap` on the parent like this:

```
.side-by-side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4px;
}
```

`Gap` very simply puts a gap between elements but like I said this isn't fully supported with early browsers so something else would be to use what's called "the lobotomized owl" which you can read about [here](https://css-tricks.com/lobotomized-owls/).

In summary, it gets all children elements that have an immediate previous sibling which means it will get all children except for the first and is scalable if you want to add more inputs.

You can try doing this:

```
.side-by-side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.side-by-side > * + *{
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding Input in a separate div

```
<div className="side-by-side">
             <div style="margin-right:100px;">
                    <Input
                      style={{ marginRight: 100 }}
                      classname="flex w-49"
                      label="first name"
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Enter first name..."
                      inputId="basicInput"
                      value={obj.firstName}                      
                    ></Input>
                </div>
                    {'          '}
                    <Input
                      classname="flex w-49"
                      label="last name"
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Enter last name..."
                      inputId="basicInput"
                      value={obj.lastName}
                    ></Input>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you've given `margin-left` to parent div with class `.side-by-side`, whereas you need to provide it to `input` element.

Below is the snippet

```css
.side-by-side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.side-by-side > input:last-of-type{
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-by-side">
  <input class="flex w-49" label="first name" type="text" placeholder="Enter first name..."></Input>
  <input class="flex w-49" label="last name" type="text" placeholder="Enter last name..."></Input>
</div>
```